# Blazor ошибка билда

Tags: c#, blazor

Начинаю осваивать Blazor, помогите собрать проект. Такое сыпится на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В солюшене присутствует global.json Ниже его содержимое

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.1.300"
  }
}
```

Всем спасибо

Comment: Так удалите этот json, зачем он вам? Либо установите sdk требуемой версии, но зачем она вам, такая старая?